# Selenium Web Driver - Error communicating with remote browser after searching

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

thanks for your time.

I have the following code (Using this to test the filter/search on my web app):
(Don't worry so much about the words I'm searching etc, I just want to get the browser working after pressing search):

```
// Store my words
String sWordOne = "HTML1";
String sWordTwo = "WONT2";
String sWordThree = "WONTWORK3";

// Add These Entries
Business_Surveys_Survey.Surveys_AddIndividualSql(sWordOne, "I have added this to check spelling", "Questions Tab Spelling");
Business_Surveys_Survey.Surveys_AddIndividualSql(sWordTwo, "I have added this to check spelling", "Questions Tab Spelling");
Business_Surveys_Survey.Surveys_AddIndividualSql(sWordThree, "I have added this to check spelling", "Questions Tab Spelling");

navigateToSurveysManageSurveys();
WebElement sSearchBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_MainContentPlaceHolderSurvey_btnSearch"));
WebElement sSearchBoxText = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_MainContentPlaceHolderSurvey_txtSearchBox"));

String sExpectedMessage = "Displaying 3 Records";
String sDisplayingXRecords = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_MainContentPlaceHolderSurvey_upSurveysList")).getText().trim();
String sSurveysOne = sDisplayingXRecords.substring(0, 20);
assertThat(sSurveysOne, containsString(sExpectedMessage));

sSearchBoxText.sendKeys("<HTML>");
sSearchBtn.click();
sSearchBoxText.clear();

String sDisplayingXRecordsOne = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_MainContentPlaceHolderSurvey_upSurveysList")).getText().trim();
String sDisplayingSurveys = sDisplayingXRecordsOne.substring(0, 20);
String sExpectedMessageTwo = "Displaying 1 Record";
assertThat(sDisplayingSurveys, containsString(sExpectedMessageTwo));

Business_Surveys_Survey.Surveys_NukeSurveyListbox();
```

Everytime it executes the following:

```
sSearchBoxText.sendKeys("<HTML>");
sSearchBtn.click();
```

it breaks and I can't talk to the browser via webdriver:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
```

I thought maybe its because im adding in some HTML tags, but even when I search for a basic word, same result.  I've tried just sending the return key in the box and pressing the search button on the page.

Any idea's? I have a suspicion its the following,

```
navigateToSurveysManageSurveys();
WebElement sSearchBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_MainContentPlaceHolderSurvey_btnSearch"));
WebElement sSearchBoxText = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_MainContentPlaceHolderSurvey_txtSearchBox"));
```

If it is can you please explain what I have done wrong and how I should be handling this better?

Thanks for your time

Comment: where is code to invoke browser? with which browser you are trying?

Comment: Hi this is handled via another class I made for logging in & Logging out, the browser call is just fine, the above code works when I pass in the full driver.findElement for both searchbox & searchbutton, when I create variables and pass them in it fails, guessing its my poor use of WebElement, im not overly familiar with this.

Comment: If you have have multiple class then either you need to declare webdriver driver in all class OR declare webdriver driver like global variable and access in another class.

Comment: there is no problem there, everything is working fine until I press the search, Opening my browser, logging in, navigating to this page is all working great, I have hundreds of other tests using these methods, all working just fine :)

Comment: can you please share that website where you are trying to click on search?

Comment: it is an internal test server, but the problem definitely is with my declaration of WebElement sSearchBtn & WebElement sSearchBoxText;
when I type this instead, everything is working:

driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_MainContentPlaceHolderSurvey_btnSearch")).click();

Comment: what is happening when you click on search? new window opening or it is searching data on same page?

Comment: did you try to use try/catch to get exact error?

Comment: Put an explicit wait for a few seconds after clicking search and see what happens. I think you need to wait for sometime. If that is the case then use waituntill in selenium to achieve what you want.